# Cambiar el tamaño del texto en barra de navegación

Tags: flutter, dart

No sé cómo cambiar el tamaño del texto en la barra de navegación `BottomNavigationBarItem`. Ésta es el código que tengo:

```
BottomNavigationBar navInferior() {
   return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white54,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: ("Inicio"),
        ),
```

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida al sitio, lee [ask] y completa el [tour], y así ganarás la primera medalla en el sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser un poco confuso porque el color y tamaño del elemento seleccionado no se especifica en el elemento en sí (`BottomNavigationBarItem`) sino en la barra de navegación que lo contiene (`BottomNavigationBar`).

En la [documentación de Flutter para `BottomNavigationBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) se espefifican qué propiedades se pueden usar en la barra de navegación. Las que te interesan para resolver este problema son:

- [`selectedItemColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#selectedItemColor): el color del elemento seleccionado (ya lo estás usando).
- [`unselectedItemColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#unselectedItemColor): el color de las opciones no seleccionadas (ya lo estás usando).
- [`selectedFontSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#selectedFontSize): el tamaño del texto de la opción seleccionada.
- [`unselectedFontSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#unselectedFontSize): el tamaño del texto de las opciones no seleccionadas.

Entonces, en el código que compartes tendrías que poner esos valores:

```
BottomNavigationBar navInferior() {
   return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white54,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedFontSize: 32,
      unselectedFontSize: 12,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: ("Inicio"),
        ),
```